# Visual Block Mode: How to insert text to multiple lines after line ending?

Tags: visual-block, multiple-lines

Below example, first line is shorter than the other lines.
I want to insert \ to all lines at the highlighted place.
[image]

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>(select all lines) , <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>\</kbd>, only first line changed.

[image]

How to get below result?
[image]

Notice: Don't want to use :s substitute command.

Comment: `:h v_b_A` if you want to have them aligned after the physical line end, you might need to `:set virtualedit`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It could be done with `virtualedit=ALL`:

1. `set virtualedit=all`
2. select visually vertical part of the text
3. `A\<ESC>`
4. return `set virtualedit=block`

See the screen:

[image]

Comment: This also works with `virtualedit=block`. Start visual block mode at the end of the first line. Then move down to the last line. Finally move to the right as far as you want. Then enter `A\<ESC>`. No need to change virtualedit setting.

Comment: It's interesting that at Step 3, `A\<ESC>` works but `I\<ESC>` (with capital i) doesn't. Unlike in the visual block without virtual edit.

Comment: Neither A or I at the Step 3 works for me. Only thing worked so far was r "replace" command. Please refer to accepted answer in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61468655/how-can-i-add-a-character-at-a-specific-column-at-the-end-of-every-line-in-vim

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is: In *Visual Block* mode select lines to their ends (`$`) and use `A` to append some text at the end of **each** line.

The longer answer:

- `gg` to go the beginning of the first line.
- `CTRL-V` (or the proper alternative `CTRL-Q` in e.g. gVim) to start blockwise visual selection.
- `jjj$` select all four lines down (`jjj`) *and* to the right until their individual ends (`$`).
- `A` start appending some text ('`\`' in your case).
- `ESC`

In fact this is not exactly your desired result, but functually equal and achievable with a minimum effort and time:

```
short line \
very long line \
very very long line \
short line \
```

Comment: I like this answer because it doesn’t require the fancy alignment: in my experience, alignment of line continuations is too much effort to maintain.

Comment: I came here looking for this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Late to the party, but any reason this only works with visual blockwise selection (i.e <kbd>C-v</kbd>) but not visual (<kbd>v</kbd>) or visual line (<kbd>Shift v</kbd>)

Comment: Only in blockwise selection mode you can use `A` to append in each line instead of the current line only.

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice technique. Thanks Maxim Kim.

This description may be helpful. All codes are literal key entries except:

- C-v for [control][v] keys combination
- ESC for [escape] key

To insert (spaces that end with char: #) on a vertical line, with cursor anywhere on the first line:

```
:set ve=all         . enable full screen block cursor access
$                   . cursor to top right position for vertical line start
C-v                 . enable select (vertical line) mode
8j                  . move cursor down 8 lines (selects a vertical line)
s#ESC               . substitute # char in highlighted area, actuate by escape key
:set ve=            . restore default mode (mine is unset, could be: block)
```

notes: can also append a char or word using an uppercase key append: A, or use insert: I